# Flutter - Row, GestureDetector and overflowed Text

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using a package where the Row and GestureDetector are on the package side, so I would like to have a solution **within the GestureDetector / wraping the Text widget, and without having to use a container with width** to resolve the overflowed text

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Testing'),
        ),
        body: Row(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              child: Text(
                'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

thank you!

Comment: Wrapping Text with Expanded widget will fix overflow issue.

Comment: @Kashifa, thank you! but inside the GestureDetector, the expanded does not work

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `GestureDetector` with `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget that'll prevent the overflow.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Testing'),
        ),
        body: Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Text(
                  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but as I said in the description of the problem ... I would need it to be inside the GestureDetector, is it possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `GestureDetector` inside `Flexible` like this:

```
       Flexible(
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Text(
              'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

result:
[image]

Comment: This works, but as I said in the description of the problem ... I would need it to be inside the GestureDetector, is it possible? Thank you!